# Django MismatchingStateError CSRF Warning

Tags: python, django, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am implementing an OAuth Authorization to connect my app to Microsoft Graph API, during callback to my URL `http://localhost:8000/callback`, the following error happens:

```
MismatchingStateError at /ms/callback
(mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/callback?code=0.AS0Al1INNTARS0G_Qyd.....
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: MismatchingStateError
Exception Value:    
(mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
```

views.py:

```py
def get_token_from_code(callback_url, expected_state):
  aad_auth = OAuth2Session(settings['app_id'],
    state=expected_state,
    scope=settings['scopes'],
    redirect_uri=settings['redirect'])

  token = aad_auth.fetch_token(token_url,
    client_secret = settings['app_secret'],
    authorization_response=callback_url)

  return token

def callback(request):
  expected_state = request.session.pop('auth_state', '')
  token = get_token_from_code(request.get_full_path(), expected_state)

  user = get_user(token)

  store_token(request, token)
  store_user(request, user)

  return HttpResponse("OK")
```

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
  path('signin', views.sign_in, name='signin'),
  path('signout', views.sign_out, name='signout'),
  path('callback', views.callback, name='callback'),
  path('callback/', views.callback, name='callback'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue and some other issues raised afterwards by doing the following steps and fixations:

1. The main reason behind state mismatch in `CSRF` token was the callback URL was redirecting to `localhost:8000/callback/` while I initiated my request to `127.0.0.1:8000` where my `Django` app was listening on `['*']` during development. I signed out from my local app and signed in again in `localhost:8000` instead.
2. There were some other `Invalid Client` errors which were fixed by changing the `Authentication` in Microsoft Azure panel like this:

[image: Azure setting]

3. Finally, when copying the `client-secret` on Azure admin panel, make sure to copy the `Value` upon creation not `Secret-ID` in your backend configuration.

[image]